# Capturar el valor de un checkbox

Tags: checkbox

estoy tratando de capturar el/los valor(es) de un checkbox en php y al imprimirlo me muestra el valor "on".
podrían ayudarme porfa. Este es el código.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="preferencia[]" value="teatro">Teatro
<input type="checkbox" name="preferencia[]" value="libros">Libros
<input type="checkbox" name="preferencia[]" value="cine">Cine


$preferencias = $_POST["preferencia"];
foreach ($preferencias as $preferencia) {
        $pre = $preferencia;
    }
```

---

//este es el formulario

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Formulario</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form method="post" action="datos.php">
    <label for="name">Nombre</label>
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text"><br>
    <br>
    <label for="apellido">Apellidos</label>
    <input id="apellido" name="apellido" type="text"><br>
    <br>
    <label >País</label>
    <select name="pais[]">
        <option value="seleccione" disabled selected>Seleccione</option>
        <option value="alemania">Alemania</option>
        <option value="italia">Italia</option>
        <option value="españa">España</option>
    </select><br>
    <br>
    <label>Preferencias</label><br>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="preferencia[]" value="teatro">Teatro
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="preferencia[]" value="libros">Libros
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="preferencia[]" value="cine">Cine
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>

//este es la de php
<?php
 if (count($_POST) > 0) {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $apellido = $_POST["apellido"];
    $paises = $_POST["pais"];
    $preferencias = $_POST["preferencia"];
    foreach ($paises as $pais){
        $imp = $pais;
    }
    foreach ($preferencias as $preferencia) {
        $pre = $preferencia;
    }
   }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Respuesta</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
    Nombre: <?=$name?>
</p>
<p>
    Apellido: <?=$apellido?>
</p>
<p>
    País: <?=$imp?>
</p>
<p>
    Preferencia: <?=$pre?>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probando el código que adjuntas veo que hace lo que se espera y recoge los valores correspondientes. Si aparecía algún `on` puede ser porque no tenía el atributo `value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con este último código, la consulta funciona.
Me he limitado a incluir en ultimo HTML dentro de la validación del post para que no genere un error en la 1er carga de la página

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Formulario</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="datos.php">
        <label for="name">Nombre</label>
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text"><br>
        <br>
        <label for="apellido">Apellidos</label>
        <input id="apellido" name="apellido" type="text"><br>
        <br>
        <label>País</label>
        <select name="pais[]">
            <option value="seleccione" disabled selected>Seleccione</option>
            <option value="alemania">Alemania</option>
            <option value="italia">Italia</option>
            <option value="españa">España</option>
        </select><br>
        <br>
        <label>Preferencias</label><br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="preferencia[]" value="teatro">Teatro
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="preferencia[]" value="libros">Libros
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="preferencia[]" value="cine">Cine
        <br>
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>


<?php
//este es la de php 
if (count($_POST) > 0) {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $apellido = $_POST["apellido"];
    $paises = $_POST["pais"];
    $preferencias = $_POST["preferencia"];
    foreach ($paises as $pais) {
        $imp = $pais;
    }
    foreach ($preferencias as $preferencia) {
        $pre = $preferencia;
    }
?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Respuesta</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>
            Nombre: <?= $name ?>
        </p>
        <p>
            Apellido: <?= $apellido ?>
        </p>
        <p>
            País: <?= $imp ?>
        </p>
        <p>
            Preferencia: <?= $pre ?>
        </p>
    </body>

    </html>
<?php
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo, no has indicado el índice de preferencia[]. Aqui te dejo el código funcional. Espero te sirva.

```
<form action="scripts.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="preferencia[0]" value="teatro">Teatro
    <input type="checkbox" name="preferencia[1]" value="libros">Libros
    <input type="checkbox" name="preferencia[2]" value="cine">Cine
    <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['preferencia'])) {
    $preferencias = $_POST["preferencia"];
    foreach ($preferencias as $preferencia) {
        $pre = $preferencia;
        echo $pre;
    }
}
?>
```

**EDIT**

Este código, también funciona, no es un problema del índice como te mencioné anteriormente

```
<form action="scripts.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="preferencia[]" value="teatro">Teatro
    <input type="checkbox" name="preferencia[]" value="libros">Libros
    <input type="checkbox" name="preferencia[]" value="cine">Cine
    <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['preferencia'])) {
    $preferencias = $_POST["preferencia"];
    foreach ($preferencias as $preferencia) {
        $pre = $preferencia;
        echo $pre;
    }
}
?>
```

Seguramente haya otro problema, tal vez si nos muestras el resto del código, por ejemplo como envías o validas el form podríamos resolverlo.

Comment: Realmente es algo sencillo, no existen validaciones y siempre doy por echo que está marcado, por eso no pongo el isset(). Estoy incursionando en esto. aqui está el código completo. Gracias por responder.